# How to fix Wordpress pagination (page not found after 8th page)

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am having trouble with Wordpress pagination. I have a custom archive page displaying custom post types from the specific category. I want to use pagination and display 12 posts per page. My problem is that pagination works correctly but only up to the 8th page. After that I am being presented with "Page not found".

I am using theme built-in function to display page navigation (1, 2... 10, 11). It correctly shows 11 pages in total, but they seem not to work after the 8th page.

```
$taxonomy = 'product_cat';
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
     'post_type' => 'product',
     'paged' => $paged,
     'posts_per_page' => '12',
     'tax_query' => array(
          array(
               'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
               'field' => 'term_id',
               'terms' => $term_id
          )
     )
);
<?php $wp_query = new WP_query( $args ); ?>
<?php if( $wp_query->have_posts() ): ?>
    <?php while( $wp_query->have_posts() ): ?>
        <?php $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
        //post content
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php s7upf_paging_nav();?>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

@edit

When I go to a different category page which should have 12 pages they work correctly up to the 9th page.
If I go to the one that has 2 pages, only the first one works.

I tried updaing permalinks. Setting posts per page to 12 in wordpress settings.

When i change posts per page in my query args to -1 it correctly shows all the posts on one page.

When manually setting the number of a page to display (`'paged' => '11'`) it also displays correct page with correct posts.

Comment: With 12 posts per page and 11 pagination count, you should be having at least 121 post of your custom post type. Just want to confirm.

Comment: @zipkundan yes, I have 125 posts in total

Comment: For testing purpose can you try echo($wp_query->post_count)? that will show you how may posts are returned y the query and probably help you troubleshoot further.

Comment: @zipkundan post_count shows 12 as set in query args

Comment: are you using any plugin for this `s7upf_paging_nav`?

Comment: @Vel 
It is a theme's function but the same happened when I created my own pagination nav

Comment: did you try with `'post_status' => 'publish'`?

Comment: @Vel just did that and no difference. all posts are published anyway

Comment: What is the base name of the template file? is it `page.php`, `index.php`, `archive-product.php`?

Comment: @janw it is `taxonomy-product_cat.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong query. On page you are creating your own query instead of the actual query the page already did.
This will also be better for performance.

**Step 1. Check what is in the normal query.**

At the top of `taxonomy-product_cat.php`

```
global $wp_query;
var_dump( $wp_query->query_vars );
```

That probably fits mostly.

**Step 2. Do the normal loop**

Remove all your query stuff (maybe keep a backup of the `$args` for the next step)

example: Replace

```
<?php if( $wp_query->have_posts() ): ?>
```

with

```
<?php if( have_posts() ): ?>
```

And so on.

**Step 3. Edit the main query**

We are going to use the hook `pre_get_posts`

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'so_53315648');
function so_53315648( WP_Query $wp_query ){
    // only check this on the main query
    if (! $wp_query->is_main_query() ){
        return;
    }
    // only check this on the product_cat taxonomy
    if ( ! $wp_query->is_tax('product_cat')) {
        return;
    }
    // maybe do some more checks?

    $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 12;

    // Is this really needed??
    //$wp_query->query_vars['posts_type'] = 'product';

    // tweak the query the way you like.
}
```

As you can see `$wp_query->query_vars` should pretty much be the same $args. But **do not overwrite it**. This might break other stuff.

Of course I could not test your specific site. But the answer should be inside the `pre_get_posts` hook. And tweaking the main query instead of doing a extra separate one.

Test, also check the `var_dump` of step 1 that your changes are coming through.
The checks at the top are to stop other pages from being affected, maybe you need more?

Let me know.

Comment: Your solution worked flawlessly, thank you very much for your effort and time!